# Am I allowed to display a small image on top of a Google Maps Static Api map?

Tags: google-maps, licenses

I am the webmaster to my company's website.

I was asked to make the Google Map on [this page](http://www.descontel.pt/index.php/pt/contactos) smaller, but the interactive map doesn't work well at all at 300x200.

I was asked to place a screenshot there but since that seems to be a violation of Google's terms I decided to use the Static Maps API.

As you can see, on the [page](http://www.descontel.pt/index.php/pt/contactos), I have a custom pointer icon. I don't want to lose it, so I intend to use HTML and CSS to place the pointer over the map, thus replacing the original pointer on the client side.

Am I allowed to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to read the [static maps terms of service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html). If there is nothing in there barring such customization then you can go ahead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I found out about and ended up using the icon:http://website.com/icon.png syntax in the URL so I really don't need to overlay anything anymore.